# Viewpager android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm working on an android app, i've a menu fragment that contains (home,logout ...), each fragment (for example homeFrag) extends Fragment, now i want to add a viewpager in my home, i've searched but i found  that my frag must extends FragmentActivity.
How can i do to implement my viewpager in my home frag ?`

```
public static class HomeFrag extends Fragment {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_discussions, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Comment: A quick search led me to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6mOK_4Zggo Basically you need to use fragment pager adapter, hopefully the video will prove helpful for you

Comment: *i found that my frag must extends FragmentActivity* <= it doesn't make sens

Comment: Please provide code about your problem and where you strugle.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not required at all. But you need a pageAdapter for this to work. Have a look at the official tutorial - 
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Just ignore the FragmentActivity part. I have used it with simple vanilla Activity class.

**Edit:**
I just read the question again and it seems that you want to ask if your Fragment not activity needs to extend the FragmentActivity. If that's the question then it's obvious that Fragment should extend fragments. FragmentActivity is for the parent activity which is holding the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your question. I am going to guess that your question really is: "how do I have a fragment hold a `ViewPager` whose pages are fragments?"

This is possible if either your `minSdkVersion` is `17` or higher *or* you are using the fragments backport from the `support-v4` or `support-v13` libraries. Only those fragment implementations support nested fragments, where a fragment holds another fragment.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) has an activity that has a fragment, and that fragment has a `ViwePager`, with fragments for its pages. The big key is that you have to pass in `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pagernested;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

Everything else is pretty much the same as if an activity were holding the `ViewPager` directly.